# Use of $.noop in jQuery UI destroy method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery UI implement destroy method. I don't understand purpose of using $.noop called with `this_.destroy()` at the beginning of method:

```
destroy: function() {
    this._destroy();
    //other code here...
    {...}
},
_destroy: $.noop,
```

Could someone explain it?

Comment: I'd assume that is for backwards compatibility for widgets written for older versions of jQuery UI.

Comment: And in which way $.noop will make it compatible?

Comment: $.noop is a placeholder function that does nothing. `$.noop = function(){};`. If it weren't assigned to $.noop, it would fail when _destroy called it unless it had a function defined on it. $.noop is much shorter than `function(){}` and gets minified better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery 1.9, the `_destroy` method was added so that widgets didn't have to call the base `destroy` method. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5056

Since the method is optional, it is by default defined as `$.noop`, which is defined as

```
$.noop = function(){};
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.noop` is just a placeholder function. In javelin.js (facebook's javascript library), it's known as "the bag of holding". There are a variety of uses, and sometimes it just makes more sense to explicitly pass a function that does nothing instead of passing nothing.

Think of my intentions with this example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'something.asmx',
    success: $.noop,
    error: $.noop,
    complete: $.noop
});
```

Clearly, the only point of this is to send data to the server and ignore all possible scenarios. Compare this to the following, where intention is ambiguous.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'something.asmx'
});
// future developer thinks, "hey, should this require some callback?
```

Comment: Ok for an ajax request, but in which way this could be usefull in a plugin destroy method where no request/param are passed?

Comment: In the case of jQueryUI, having `$.noop` for a destroy method implies that one intentionally does not exist (yet), and is not just missing by accident. It may also may be because the interface requires having a destroy method, but this particular widget does not, thus passing an empty function to satisfy the basic interface requirement.